# Returning Images from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am making a Web Api and I need to return multiple images to the client. I am currently using a Base64 string for each image but this results in each request taking far too long. Is there a better, more efficient way of returning images?

This is the code I am using:

Controller:

```
    public LearningUnits GetLearningUnits([FromODataUri]Guid key)
    {
        var record = db.LearningUnits.SingleOrDefault(inst => inst.LearningUnitId == key);

        record.ImageURLPath = ImageHandler.ImageToByteArrayFromFilePath(record.ImageURLPath);

        return record;
    }
```

ImageToByteArray Method:

```
    public static string ImageToByteArrayFromFilePath(string imagefilePath)
    {
        byte[] imageArray = File.ReadAllBytes(imagefilePath);

        string baseImage = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);

        return baseImage;
    }
```

Comment: How many such images are there in total?

Comment: Why can't you return url in your model, and then the client will make further requests to get image binaries?

Comment: Depends on the amount of records in the database. Each record has an image. So it could be 1 to 1000.

Comment: @WadeFerreira: Returning "1000 images" would certainly explain why the request takes a long time.  *Normally* an API would return data which references other resources (such as images) by supplying the URLs for those resources, and consumers of the data would make separate requests for those other resources as needed.  When a client requests 1000 records, are they *really* going to want all of those images as well in the same request?  What is the use case for this data?

Comment: Store the Base64 string or just provide a url for the client to the image.

Comment: @Mufaka - a `Base64` string for image content would only exacerbate the problem as it adds more bloat to the already large payload.

Comment: @Igor isn't the payload already a Base64 string?

Comment: @Mufaka - you are right I missed that and see that now in the OPs code.

Comment: Along the lines of what @tenbits said. I completely agree but if you can't do that (*lets say the image is not available in the web site path*) then create an alias or identifier for each image. Return those to the client and use them to build up urls in the HTML (or dynamically later on if needed). Create either a Web API call or an HttpHandler or HttpModule and have that code serve up the images based on the incoming id. The benefit of that is you can still build a url in the html which would also allow the browser to use caching to store the images.

Comment: @David The use case is a mobile app that contains lists of Courses, each containing modules and each of those containing learning units. Each record in each list has an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use media formatters, so that when the Web API is queried with a particular type, you'll then receive the actual binary stream of the particular type.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

This is the standard RESTful pattern; you have the same URL, but when you want a JSON record for the data, you accept-type:application/json, but you change your MIME request type to image/png or something similar when you want that media type.

More can be found here:
[How to provide custom mediatype formats for OData Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291547/how-to-provide-custom-mediatype-formats-for-odata-api)

Odata also implicitly supports it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.formatter.odatamediatypeformatter(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: It is not a good idea to return different data for a single endpoint. MediaFormatters are good only for different formatting of the **same** data. Otherwise it violets the single responsibility principle and is not a common RESTful pattern. Surely you can return the image instead of json, but only in case when the image completely represents the data.

Comment: I respectfully disagree; if the image is representative of the entity in question, then you could argue that it is the content type of that particular entity. If there is only one image visualisation for a  data entity, then that image visualisation is appropriate even if the image isn't the full representation of the entire entity (which anyway may include telemetry, etc. from something like OData). 

If we took your logic to its full conclusion, then we shouldn't even represent the object as a application/json or application/xml because it differs fundamentally from data's native form.

Comment: The naming `MediaType`**`Formatter`** says, that only the formatter differs for the entity. Sure, by serializing the data to particular type, there could be more or less information present. Consider the endpoint `[get]/api/v1/blog/123`, when requesting it with `accept:image/png` it is not enough to return just a main image of the blog post, but it would be ok if you generate the image with the title over it. If someone wants to return just a property value like `ImageURLPath`, then the explicit endpoint should be defined: `[get]/api/v1/blog/123/image`.

Answer (score 1):

If the endpoint returns json, then there is no other way, beyond `base64`, how to embed binaries within the response. But it is definitely a bad idea due to the performance issues. May be for some icons it would be ok, but for larger images its not suitable.

So the best solution here, is to return the url to the image. And the client will make further request to get raw bytes for the image.

Also worth to mention, the image url can not only be the path to the static file, but also a path to some webapi endpoint, which, for instance, gets the image bytes by the resource id and sends the client raw binary back, and not a json string.

Comment: I've decided to go this route. I haven't found any better options and this would be the most efficient